# Find all the solutions to the equation: $e^z = e^{-1 + i\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Im slightly stuck on hiw to attampt this...
I thought to write both sides in polar form, 
ie.
$$e^x (\cos(y) + i\sin(y)) = e^{-1}(\cos(\pi)+i\sin(\pi))$$

I could equate it from here i think, but it specifically says in the question find ALL the solutions to the equation.
By doing it this way, i think i would only find one.
I know i need to add $2k\pi$ in at some point. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use that $\ker (\exp)=2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You're going in the right direction. From your equation, can you derive what $x$ is? Then, take the real part of both sides of the equation. Can you derive possible values for $y$? Can you check that you have indeed found precisely the solutions to the equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Robert's hint, note that your equation is equivalent to
\begin{align*}
e^{z + 1 - i\pi} = 1.
\end{align*}
Hence $z+1-i\pi = 2\pi i n$ for some integer $n$. Solving for $z$, we find that
\begin{align*}
z = 2\pi i n + i \pi - 1 = i\pi (2n + 1) - 1,
\end{align*}
for integers $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $e^w = 1$, then $w = 2 \pi i n$ for some integer $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The exponential map is 1-1 on the strip $\{x+iy : -\pi \le y < \pi \}$ and $e^z = e^{z+2n\pi i}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Since $z = -1 +i\pi$ is one solution of it. So, $z = -1 + i(\pi +2n\pi)$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ are all the solutions of your equation.